# If $a \cdot a = a$ then $a=0$ or $a=1$?

Tags: proof-verification

> If $a\cdot a = a$ then $a=0$ or $a=1$?

Where $a \in \mathbb{R}.$

I try this way:

Suppose that a is different to $0$ it implies the existence of multiplicative inverse:

$$a^{-1}(a\cdot a)=a^{-1}\cdot a$$

$$(a^{-1}a)= 1~~~~~\text{(by associativity)}$$

$$1\cdot a=1~~~~~\text{(multiplicative inverse)}$$

Therefore $a=1$.

Is this even possible to negate one of my conclusion to get to the other one and then do the same to prove the other conclusion or this is terribly wrong? I appreciate every help I'm losing myself.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: oh yeahnext time i will do better i'm new here

Comment: You can [edit] the question, you know? Try MathJax too :)

Comment: yeah it is in the real numbers field I forget about that

Comment: Your argument is fine, but in the presentation you are missing one (trivial) part. You should start by showing that $0\cdot 0 = 0$ proving that $0$ satisfy it. Having done that you can assume $a\not =0$ for which your argument shows that $a=1$.

Answer (score 3):

You claim that if $a$ is different from $0$, then it has a multiplicative inverse. This is only true if you're working over a field such as the real numbers. In general, this doesn't have to be true.

A concrete counterexample to your claim is ${\mathbb Z}[X]/(X^2-X)$ and $a$ equal to (the residue class of) $X$. By construction, $a^2 = a$, but $a$ is neither $0$ nor $1$.

Over a field, your reasoning is correct. I'd shorten it to simply: $a^2 = a$ $\Rightarrow$ $a(a-1) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a = 0$ or $a-1 = 0$.

Comment: Please address this: *Is this even possible to negate one of my conclusion to get to the other one and then do the same to prove the other conclusion or this is terribly wrong?* I think that is the main question, pedagogically.

Comment: @Shaun You may be right. I can't look in the OPs mind, though, so I'll wait for clarification.

Comment: The field im working on is in the real numbers where a belongs

Answer (score 2):

A priori you cannot assume there exists a multiplicative inverse.

Instead, using associativity (I hope you have that, at least) rewrite $a^2=a$ as $a\cdot(a-1)=0$. Now it all depends on the fact if your ring allows [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) or not. If it does not, then either $a=0$ or $a=1$, otherwise not.

Comment: By ring u refering to the field?

Comment: If you are working over a field, then your argumentation is perfectly fine

Comment: yeah it is in the real numbers,  a=0 or a=1 it is fine if I just prove one of the conclusions?